# SQL - Need to find duplicates where one column can have multiple values

Tags: sql

I am pretty sure this SQL requires using GROUP BY and HAVING, but not sure how to write it.

I have a table similar to this:

| ID | Cust# | Order# | ItemCode | DataPoint1 | DataPoint2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | 123 | I | xxxyyyxxx | 123456 |
| 2 | 001 | 123 | Insert | xxxyyyxxx | 123456 |
| 3 | 001 | 123 | Delete | asdf | 9999 |
| 4 | 001 | 123 | D | asdf | 9999 |

In this table Rows 1 & 2 are effectively duplicates, as are rows 3 & 4.
This is determined by the ItemCode having the value of 'I' or 'Insert' in rows 1 & 2.  And 'D' or 'Delete' in rows 3 & 4.

How could I write a SQL select statement to return rows 2 and 4, as I am interested in pulling out the duplicated rows with the higher ID value.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the "offending" column with a consistent value.  Then, you can use `row_number()` or a similar mechanism:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by Cust#, Order#, left(ItemCode, 1), DataPoint1, DataPoint2
                                order by id asc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum > 1;
```

Note:  Not all databases support `left()`, but all support the functionality somehow.  This does assume that the first character of the `ItemCode` is sufficient to identify identical rows, regardless of the value.